# Creating polygon from vertices alorithm

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics

Is there somebody who can describe a theory behind creating quads from pointcloud(vertices) in blender python ? Is the only way to check length betweeen vertices like:
(theory)

```
for i = number of vertices :
 for y = number of vertices :
  if (length between vertex(i) and vertex(y)) < (set number):
  add y to array
 create quad from array #but i dont know how to say dont use the vertex where are more than 5 edges ...
```

But maybe whole my thinking about the problem is bad ... can somebody help me with it? Or maybe there are more elegant mathematical solution - i dont know.

[image]

Comment: There's too many, search for "3d convex hull algorithms".

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know, how to ask uncle google.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried to look at many themes about 3D convex hull but I can't use it for blender and the vertices. I am too weak scripter for that I think. Can you provide me some better advice, please? (prosim pekne)